# Hibernate mapping of an Enum which implements an interface (i.e. is a subclass)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, enums, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting my feet wet with Hibernate, and I've run into a problem which I can't find any solution to.

I have an interface `MyInterface` and an enum implementing the interface:

```
class MyInterface {
    void someMethod();
}

enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {

    INST1, INST2;

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(I also have a few other implementations of `MyInterface` but I don't think that matters.)

Now I'm trying to map the implementations of `MyInterface` (where `MyEnum` is one of them) using the one table per class hierarchy scheme. I know how to map ordinary enums as properties, and I know how to map ordinary subclasses, but I don't know how to do the combo. Mixing the two techniques as follows

```
-- DOES NOT WORK. --

<subclass name="package.MyEnum" extends="package.MyInterface">
    <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">package.MyEnum</param>
    </type>
</subclass>
```

is apparently not supported.

Any help appreciated.

(I realize that I could work around the problem by creating something like

```
class MyEnumWrapper implements MyInterface {
    MyEnum inst;

    public void someMethod() {
        inst.someMethod();
    }
}
```

in which case an ordinary subclass-mapping would do, but I'd rather avoid this if possible. I have no problem implementing custom UserTypes though.)

Comment: Why do you want to map an enum to a table? An enum should be immutable, and it has a fix number of instances, so you have everything you need without mapping anything: it's all in the source code. Moreover, Hibernat wouldn't be able to have a separate copy of your enum per session, so it can't work.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, thanks for reading my question, I appreciate it. I need to persist a class that looks like `class MyClass { MyInterface obj; }`. This means AFAIK, that I need to persist `MyInterface`-instances as well and `MyEnum` is one of them. I don't see how `MyEnum` instances being immutable/fixed number of instances changes anything. I still need to keep track of *which* instance the other objects refer to. As I said, I'm quite new to this, so bare with me if there's something fundamental that I'm missing.

Comment: An entity must have a constructor, called by Hibernate. This is sufficient to rule out enums. It's hard to say if it's the best solution without more context, but you could indeed wrap the enum into an entity.

Comment: hmm... That makes sense. And with UserTypes I define "custom columns" rather than "custom tables", so those won't help me in this situation I suppose?

Comment: This is kind of annoying because I have hundreds of enum constants, and having to change from `INST` to `new MyEntity(INST)` in every place that I use them is going to be a pain. :-(